# Why pointer char arrays dont get NULL automatically at the end?

Tags: c

In the following code i am printing a pointer array. I am terminating the while loop while it gets a `NULL` but this is not terminating. Why it is not getting a `NULL`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *a[] = { "This is", "a story", "of a person" };

    while (a[i] != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", a[i]);
        i++;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

This is my GDB debugging session:

```
30      while (a[i] != NULL) {
(gdb) p a[0]
$1 = 0x8048510 "This is"
(gdb) p a[1]
$2 = 0x804851b "a story"
(gdb) p a[2]
$3 = 0x8048523 "of a person"
(gdb) p a[3]
$4 = 0x8048480 <__libc_csu_init> "UW1\377VS\350\305\376\377\377\201\303u\033"
```

At `a[3]` why it is not `NULL`. To get a `NULL` Why I have to declare an explicit 0 at the end of the array like this:

```
char *a[] = { "This is", "a story", "of a person", NULL };
```

Why we have do that?

Comment: Why not? You won't always need to insert a NULL pointer at the end, it depends of a lot of things that C can't guess.

Comment: thanks...nouney
nice answer! Karol S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for string literals implicitly terminated by a zero-byte, everything should be explicit in C. So code with an explicit terminating `NULL` pointer like:

```
 char *a[] = {"This is","a story","of a person", NULL};
```

BTW you might want `const char*a[]` instead of `char*a[]` (e.g. because you want `a` to be in a `.rodata` read-only data segment, if that makes sense for your implementation).

Answer (score 1):

`a` will be of size 3 and thus accessing `a[3]` invokes undefined behavior. Anything can be stored in that cell and of course c will not guarantee it is `NULL`.

Comment: is this by default in c that "a" will be of size 3??

Comment: @quidstone No, it's because you put 3 strings in `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Why it should have NULL there?

You may be confused by the fact that `"quoted strings"` are zero-terminated. That is, each of your strings `"This is"`, `"a story"`, etc. has a ASCII NUL character `'\0'` at the end—but not the array of strings (pointers to chars) which has exactly 3 elements as you defined.

Also, it's better to make the array contain `const char *`, not just `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

The length of `a` is `3` because you give it three elements to initialize. Accessing `a[3]` would be illegal.

You can add a null pointer to the end of the initialization. Or, another possible solution is to give it a length of `4`explicitly:

```
char *a[4] = {"This is","a story","of a person"};
```

In this way, `a[3]` is initialized as a null pointer.

Comment: Shouldn't it start with 0 and as i am giving 3 elements so it should have a buffer size of 2 as 0,1,2?

Comment: @quidstone The buffer size is not the bigger index of the array, it's the number of indexes, it is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

The null character that ends char * is '\0', not true for char*[]

a[3] in your case would contain garbage from the actual memory address in the RAM.

You should end your array explicitly with a null if you are somehow not sure about the size of the array.